# How to Build a Segment Tree Given a Circular Array?

Tags: arrays, segment-tree

Given a **circular** array A, how would you construct a segment tree off of A? Do you use two separate arrays for the segment tree or some other method?

If possible, it would also be **very helpful** if someone could explain how the range update and range queries would work for such a case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only use segment trees for associative operations, like "sum" and "min" and "xor", where if I give you the result for [*start*, *mid*) and [*mid*, *end*), you can directly compute the result for [*start*, *end*).

So you don't actually need to do anything special for circular arrays; you can build and maintain your segment tree exactly the same as if the array were *not* interpreted as circular. To compute the result for an interval of the form [*greater_index*, *lesser_index*) that wraps around the end of the array, just use the normal method to compute the results for [*greater_index*, *array_size*) and [0, *lesser_index*), and combine them as normal.

Comment: @zrli: You're welcome!